# Issues recompiling XMonad

Tags: haskell, archlinux, xmonad

A few days ago I got an error related to udiskie tray icon in order to appear on xmobar when I start xmonad. Before I got the error message it was working fine. Here is the error message I got:

```
XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/arturo/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/arturo/.xmonad/xmonad.hs
xmonad.hs:105:5: error:
• Couldn't match expected type: (String -> X ()) -> String -> X a0
with actual type: X ()
• The function ‘spawnOnce’ is applied to three value arguments,
but its type ‘String -> X ()’ has only one
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
spawnOnce "udiskie -t &" spawnOnce "volumeicon &"
In the expression:
do spawnOnce "lxsession &"
spawnOnce "picom &"
spawnOnce "nm-applet &"
spawnOnce "udiskie -t &" spawnOnce "volumeicon &"
....
|
105 |     spawnOnce "udiskie -t &"
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
Please check the file for errors.
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
```

Can someone tell me what's happening and if it is possible to solve the issue? I googled around, but couldn't find something related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Haskell issue (rather than XMonad and definitely not Arch - maybe you want to adjust the tags).

The key line in the error message is

```
The function ‘spawnOnce’ is applied to three value arguments,
but its type ‘String -> X ()’ has only one
```

Your Haskell file contains the line

```hs
spawnOnce "udiskie -t &" spawnOnce "volumeicon &"
```

and the compiler tries to treat `"udiskie -t &"`, `spawnOnce` and `"volumeicon &"` as three arguments to (the first) `spawnOnce`. I'd suppose you mistakenly cancelled a line break before (the second) `spawnOnce`.
Make it

```hs
spawnOnce "udiskie -t &"
spawnOnce "volumeicon &"
```

and each each `spawnOnce` will have its one argument.